# The Passive Voice when referring to time

Tags: tenses, past-tense, passive-voice, time, active-voice

If we say something like "More than two months have passed", would you say this is speaking in the Passive Voice? When you look at the general rules about when to use the Passive Voice, it doesn't seem to mention the passing of time, so I'm wondering why we say it this way.

Comment: In my opinion the only passive voice rule that matters is to remember that the other "rules" are actually only guidelines and mainly a matter of style rather than correctness.

Comment: It's not the passive voice.

Comment: The passive voice would use "are passed" not "have passed".

Comment: The metaphor of time being a river (and the simile "time like an ever-rolling stream") is applicable. I don't think there's a passive voice for flowing water either.

Answer (score 2):

It is in the active voice because it is the months that passed.

To put it in the passive voice, it would have to use a form of "to be" as well, such as this:

> More than two months were wasted.